# Outlook 2016 Module Extension

Tags: office365, office-addins, office-js, outlook-2016

I have tried to use the new Module Extension Type as described [here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Outlook-Add-in-JavaScript-ModuleExtension). After following the Installation steps I can indeed add the Extension from the Manifest file and the provided images are loaded in the Webfrontend (used the DEBUG express Options to verify what files were requested) but the AddIn itself is not Loading.

I followed all the steps described in the Readme.md of the Project but couldn't manage to get it working

Here is what I tried:

- I tried updating but my Office 2016 is already up to date (16.0.6965).
- I tried running it against a Exchange Account on my Test installation (Exchange 2013)
- I tried running it against an 365 Office.com Account
- I tried running it from VS2015 (had to get some extra xsd files since VersionOverrides1_1 were not included in the Latest update of the Office Tools
- I tried building it from scratch but to no success

Is there anything I did not try to get it running or are there any other example I could try?